# Why does deploying chaincode in hyperledger not work?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I am working on the `hyperledger fabric v2.0` and after I have set up the network, created the channels I am not able to set the chaincode.

The Linux command: *`./network.sh deployCC`* was not working.
So it says i should use the ollowing valid call example:
*`./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go`*

If I use this command, I recieve the following error:

```
Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: go: inconsistent vendoring in /home/akosua/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go:
    github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.3.2: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go@v0.0.0-20200424173110-d7076418f212: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go@v1.1.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go@v0.0.0-20200424173316-dd554ba3746e: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.5.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt

run 'go mod vendor' to sync, or use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to ignore the vendor directory: exit status 1
Chaincode packaging has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

I updated the current `golang (v1.15)`

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I reproduced your situation, I solved it through the method below.

1. To install the smart contract dependencies, run the following command

- [fabric-docs/chaincode](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html?highlight=GO111MODULE)

```sh
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples
cd asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go && \
GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor
```

2. run `deployCC` command in `test-network`

```sh
cd test-network && \
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
```

---

[EDIT]

After checking your answer, I reproduced your situation again. I wrote the order as it was.

**first assumtion**

1-1. I thought that apt update had no effect at all, and it was solved by deleting the previously incorrectly created/installed file from `./network.sh down`.

1-2. Therefore, after installing the wrong vendor, I artificially executed and executed the command, and produced the same error.

1-3. However, in the `./network.sh down` command, the vendor was not cleared, and in the up command, the method suggested in the above answer was executed in the script.

1-4. The error was not resolved, and I had to find another problem.

**The other assumption**

- While analyzing the `./network.sh down` script, it was confirmed that the docker volume was cleared.
- It was assumed that the problem occurred because a package containing the wrong vendor remained on the docker volume.

2-1. As in the initial assumption, the `deployCC` command was executed based on the wrong vendor.

2-2. After the same error occurred, the network was shut down without clearing the volume of the docker network.

2-3. After replacing the chaincode with the correct vendor, reloading the network, and executing the `deployCC` command.

2-4. The same error occurred, and the remaining volume was confirmed to have an effect.

2-5. The entire network was evaporated through the `-v` option. In addition, all unnecessary volumes were evaporated through the `docker volume prune`.

2-6. After that, the network was reloaded and the `deployCC` command was executed, and it was confirmed that it was working normally.

In other words, the file related to the **previous wrong chaincode remained in the dokcer volume**, and it seems to have been resolved as it was deleted by a script that evaporates the volume in `./network.sh down` together.

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) # This is a dangerous command because all containers are erased.
docker volume prune
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ myeonkil kim ! I really appreciate your work!

Comment: And thanks also for modifying my coment.  So I tried your comments at 1., but unfortunately the data cannot be found. I think my problem is something with the `go path` . So I tried to set up go path by the following instruction: [link] https://medium.com/learn-go/go-path-explained-cab31a0d90b9 . Afterwards I checkted [link] https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html?highlight=GO111MODULE   - but till now, I could not find any solution, which worked for my problem :/

Comment: If you have set GOPATH well, and if you have done well, you will need to check if you have followed the $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger directory path created in the above answer. If it is not solved, it will be more helpful if you inform us about additional work and problems.

Comment: Thanks @myeongkil kim. the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger` is still not working. So what I have done so far: I have completly deletet golang and installed it again with: `wget https://golang.org/dl/go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gzsudo chown -R root:root ./go
sudo mv go /usr/local` . And then I continued with this instruction: [link]https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html **Package the smart contract** .

Comment: Everything of the instruction (see link above) worked out until **Install the chaincode package** with the following command  `peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz` . I got the Error: `chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode' .... ` . So still trying to solve this, until I can deploy the chaincode, I guess

Comment: @Kate I read your answer and added a new workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake/solution now.

First I checked for updates again: `sudo apt update`

Then I put the network down and up:

`./network.sh down` and than open it again by `./network.sh up`

Afterwards I could continue without errors